# Как заменить текст c помощью jQuery или JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть [сайт](http://eliteproxies.ru/), раздел Акции. Нужно заменить текст "Weeks", Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds на русский. Как заменить текст c помощью jQuery или JavaScript?

Comment: eprivalov1, вам нужно добавть интернационализацию на сайт?

Comment: Исправьте в этом файле: http://eliteproxies.ru/wp-content/themes/enfold/js/shortcodes.js?ver=3 , 210 строчка.

Comment: @romes пока нет, нужно просто перевести английский текст на русский язык

Comment: @romeo Если править эту строку, то счетчик перестает работать...

Comment: `$('body').html($('body').html().replace('Weeks', 'Недели'))`... *Шутка*

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.av-countdown-weeks .av-countdown-time-label').html("Недели");
});
```

И далее в таком же стиле)

Comment: Я плюсанул, спасибо за помощь, но именно в этом случае не работает!

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.av-countdown-weeks .av-countdown-time-label').html("Недели");
    });
Или какую еще ошибку выдает?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('div[data-label="Week"]').html('Неделя');
```

И так далее